# Is there a way to force an RPART model to use a certain variable?

Tags: r, rpart

I'm running a model using rpart, which ends up actually abandoning one of the main independent variables in its final tree. Is there a way to force usage of that variable?

```
model <- rpart(dependent ~  desiredforcevar + var2 + var3, method="class", data=df_smote)
```

Comment: Exactly like this: `dependent ~  desiredforcevar + var2 + var3`..What do you mean by "abandoning" and "main"?

Comment: main I just mean it's my variable of interest. By abandoning, it's leaving that variable out of the model, presumably because of its low variable.importance

Comment: Then probably your assumptions aren't right? I don't think this is on topic here, maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is more suited. But you need to improve your question with a better example.